# rdfstore-js: Stand-alone SPARQL end-point- access remotely in javascript

Tags: javascript, curl, rdf, sparql

I could run the rdfstore-js as Stand-alone SPARQL end-point. The example in README file sends a SPARQL query using command line program curl:

`curl -v -d "default-graph-uri=http://test.com/graph1" --data-urlencode "query=select * { ?s ?p ?o } limit 3" -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://localhost:8080/sparql`

I need to access it remotely using javascript in a browser and not in command line program. The examples in README do not show how to access a remote SPARQL endpoint in javascript; they just show how to create local rdfstores and query them. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: This isn't really specific to RDF or SPARQL.  Curl is just making an HTTP request.  All you should need to do is use a Javscript library that can do the same and request the same URL (`http://localhost:8080/sparql`) with the same parameters.

Comment: Could  you please help me on how I can write the javascript code that does the same as this curl command?